# Advanced MySQL left join IFNULL Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for help with an advanced MySQL query. My current query, shown below, works fine. I would like to add an additional field, so I don't have to create a separate query. The new field, count(`TableA.Field05`), should result in the total number of records from `TableA`.

TableA  has 10 records 
TableB  has 100 records

```
SELECT count(TableB.Answer) AS unAnswered 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON ( TableA.Field01 = TableB.fkField01 AND TableA.Field02 = TableB.fkField02 AND TableB.Answer = '1') 
WHERE TableB.fkField03 IS NULL AND TableA.Field04 = 10 
GROUP BY TableA.Field01, TableA.Field02
```

Result:

`unAnswered = 8` this is correct

The desired result is:

`unAnswered = 8
count(TableA.Field05) = 10`

--

This is an example of the data and results.

```
SELECT count(TableB.Answer) AS unAnswered
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON ( TableA.Field01 = TableB.fkField01 AND TableA.Field02 = TableB.fkField02 AND TableB.Answer = '1')
WHERE TableB.fkField03 IS NULL AND TableA.Field04 = 10
GROUP BY TableA.Field01, TableA.Field02

TableA
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 1, Field03 = 10
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 2, Field03 = 21
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 3, Field03 = 22
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 4, Field03 = 34

TableB
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 1, Answer = 1
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 2, Answer = 1
Field01 = 1, Field02 = 3, Answer = 1
Field01 = 2, Field02 = 1, Answer = 1
Field01 = 2, Field02 = 2, Answer = 1
Field01 = 2, Field02 = 3, Answer = 1

Result
count(TableB.Answer) AS unAnswered = 1


Result trying to achive
count(TableB.Answer) AS unAnswered = 1
count(TableA.Field03) = 4
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you add `COUNT(tableA.field05)`? Please show some sample data and expected results, as well as explain a little more why this query doesn't work.

Comment: When I add count(TableA.Field05), I get unAnswered = 8 and count(TableA.Field05) = 8

Comment: I would try to add some sample data to your question or build an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) so I can see what you are trying to do and help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out my own question.

```
SELECT **COALESCE(count(DISTINCT TableB.Answer)) AS unAnswered, count(DISTINCT TableA.Field05)**
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON ( TableA.Field01 = TableB.fkField01 AND TableA.Field02 = TableB.fkField02 AND TableB.Answer = '1') 
WHERE TableB.fkField03 IS NULL AND TableA.Field04 = 10 
GROUP BY TableA.Field01, TableA.Field02
```

Adding COALESCE and DISTINCT solved my issue. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to add the count of tableA to your current query just add it to your select statement:

'SELECT count(TableB.Answer) AS unAnswered, count(TableA.Field02) FROM TableA ...'

Comment: No, I am trying to get both answers out of one query.

Comment: How about using a UNION statement like `SELECT count(TableA.Field05) FROM TableA UNION SELECT count(TableB.Answer) FROM TableB ...`

Comment: It looks like it has possibilities, but it adds the results as rows. I am trying to get both results on the same row.